# two static methods running in separate thread call a static method which add things to list but list doesn't get mixed

Tags: java

```
public class StaticTestPrototype implements Runnable{
public StaticTestPrototype() {
}

static ArrayList<String> hostList(String protocol){ 
    ArrayList<String> hosts = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        hosts.add(protocol+i);
    }
    return hosts;
}

static void allsnmp(){
    ArrayList<String> snmphosts = hostList("snmp");
}

static void allssh(){
    ArrayList<String> sshhosts = hostList("linux"); 
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("allsnmp_real")){
        try {
            StaticTestPrototype.allsnmp();  //static method
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("allssh_real")) {
        try {
            StaticTestPrototype.allssh();  //static method
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

}

```
//somewhere from main i do 
//Thread t1 = new Thread(new StaticTestPrototype(), "allsnmp_real");t1.start();
//Thread t2 = new Thread(new StaticTestPrototype(), "allssh_real");t2.start();
```

static method allsnmp running in a      thread calls static method hostList.
static method allssh  running in another thread calls static method hostList.
since there is one copy of hostList which is being called from allsnmp and allssh, 
why the contents of returned ArrayList doesn't get mixed?

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense to me.  What do you think there's only one copy of?

Comment: @DavidWallace I think the OP is assuming the returned object of a static method is `static` or associated with the class instead of the instance.

Comment: @DavidWallace In the class StaticTestPrototype there will be one copy of all the static methods ,and two objects of the class will act on that single copy only not like instance method where object can have separate copy

Comment: You mean one copy of the byte code for the method?  Sure.  But you can call it twice, and get two separate outputs.  Also, every local variable defined inside the method has a separate copy for each call to the method.

Comment: The same applies to instance methods.  You don't get separate copies of instance methods.  The only thing that's special about an instance method is that it has access to one extra object - the object that you wrote before the dot when you called it.

Comment: So for instance methods every object has a pointer or handle to access that method ,but in case of static method there is only one pointer or handle which can be used by each object turn by turn.

Comment: No.  That is really not how it works.  Any number of threads can be running the same method at the same time, regardless of whether it is an instance method or a static method.

Answer (score 2):

Within the code there are no static fields created, each static method returns a new instance of the `ArrayList`.  When a thread calls the static methods it receives its own instance of the `List` created by the static method.

If you had a field declared within the class and the static methods returned this field that would create an issue.

```
public class StaticTestPrototype{

    //This static field would be shared by all instances.
    public static List<String> hosts = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static getHosts(){
       return hosts;
    }

    public static getHosts2(){
       return new ArrayList<String>(); 
      //this is a separate instance not associated with the class
      //instead associated with the instance.
    }
}
```

Comment: So for instance methods every object has a pointer or handle to access that method ,but in case of static method there is only one pointer or handle which can be used by each object turn by turn.

Comment: @user2734915 `static` means that an object/field belongs to the class and not the instance.  That is why you can call static methods without an instance of the class, `ie: StaticTestPrototype.getHosts()`.  The `static` keyword has no impact on the object returned from a `static` method.  If you return a new instance of an object from a static method, each instance created by the method has its own reference and space in memory.

Answer (score 1):

`hosts` is a local variable in the static method `hostList`. Each invocation of `hostList` will have its own copy of the list.

Compare with the following code where `hosts` is a static variable:

```
static ArrayList<String> hosts = new ArrayList<String>();

static ArrayList<String> hostList(String protocol){     
   for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
     hosts.add(protocol+i);
   }
   return hosts;
}
```

However, it would be unsafe to access the `ArrayList` from different threads at the same time in this  manner, because several  could be trying to modify the list at the same time, with unpredictable results.